How do you cite an entire magazine/periodical?
I have a class where I am supposed to talk about advertising in magazines, and I can't find any information on how to cite the entire magazine/periodical. I have to talk about the trends I generally see, so I think I need to cite the entire periodical/magazine. I am going to also reference some specific articles and advertisements, but in the assignment, it says to cite the magazine correctly, and I can't figure it out. It is supposed to be in MLA format.

Have you tried asking the professor?

Are you trying to say something like, ‘Lots of people find Time [1] to be interesting’?

Of course there are times when the entire journal should be cited.  Journal A [1] allows political advertising, but Journal B [2] does not.

You might need to get some clarity about what your professor means by "cite the magazine correctly." They might not be telling you to cite the entire publication. It might be general guidance to make sure you follow the MLA format when citing the magazine with the expectation that you are citing something specific.

Magazines may have the same articles but different adverts in different regions, e.g., North America vs Europe. Just to make it more difficult...

I expect that you're having trouble finding how to do that, because you should not do that.
The point of a citation is to link to something concrete that another person can look up and verify. It should be as precise as possible, so as to save the verifier time (down to the page number or line if viable).
What is a reader supposed to do with a reference to, say, a whole book, or the entire history of a periodical? Read the whole thing to verify your observations about trends?
But ask your professor to be sure.

I would assume OP means they don't know how to cite an entire issue, but know how to cite an article. I don't think they mean cite just "TIME."

I’d think that one would have the magazine name, date of issue on the cover, and publisher info.

I would say if you are talking about the layout and design of something, this often is expressed through all publications or at least more than one article.

A citation should be as precise or broad as is appropriate to the claim it’s being cited for — which usually means as precise as possible, but not always.  If I’m giving a citation for a single fact, then I’ll cite a page or theorem number.  If the citation is for an author’s overall argument, then it’s often appropriate to cite a whole article, chapter, or even book.  If the citation is to back up a claim about — for instance — the gender distribution of authors in some periodical over time, then it would be appropriate to cite the whole range under consideration.

Example of a situation where you have to do that: "We reviewed the issues of weekly sports magazines on sale during the Olympics. We found magazines sold in the country of the Olympics had 77% of their full-page advertising themed with the Games [1-5], while those sold in neighboring countries had 60% [6-12]." In many journals, this would be better served as a supplemental data table or file, but in other titles, and class papers, you don't get that.

Consider a scientist who studies beetles, and has made a particular investigation of the habits of Badister dilatatus. Would you expect them to cite the beetle?  Of course not! The beetle is the subject of their study, not a citable source.
This is your situation, except you are studying magazines, and you've made a particular investigation of the advertising in Time.  The magazine is the subject of your study, and not a citable source.
However if you refer to a particular advert, you can cite it in the normal way, giving the title, date, page number of each particular advert.

Exactly; OP should include in their methods section how they obtained their data, which should include enough detail that someone else could plausibly obtain the same sort of data. That'll likely include more than just the issue number, it should include some mention of how they decided on that particular issue ("most recent available" might be one way), but is not "citation" per se. However, since OP is doing this for a course, their instructor's view is probably more important that what makes more sense broadly.

The goal of a citation is to provide the reader with the information they need to find your source and reproduce your results.  You are creating a paper trail of ideas, which people coming after you can follow.  This is very important in academia—there is a famous quote from Newton: "If I have seen further than others, it is by standing upon the shoulders of giants."  We need to know whose shoulders we are standing upon, if for no other reason than if one of those giants turns out to be wrong, we can figure out which following results need to be reconsidered.
Also, I think that it is important to note that, outside of the classroom, no one really cares about the formatting of your citations.  Citations on informally published work (e.g. citations in a StackExchange answer, citations on a blog, citations in your own personal notes) just need to contain the important information, and if you are writing something for publication, whatever journal you are submitting to will have some specific format that they want and it should be easy enough to simply format your citations in that manner.  Moreover, most serious academics use some kind of citation management system (EndNote is a fancy tool; I use a variation of BibTeX, and so on).  As a user of such a tool, you enter the appropriate information into some kind of database and when you cite one of the sources you've entered, an appropriate reference / bibliography entry is automatically generated for you.
If you are planning to continue in academia for any length of time, it might be worthwhile to learn how to use one of those tools.
In general, there are some basic data which one might expect in a citation for a magazine / periodical (e.g. Time or National Geographic):

Name:  What is the name of the magazine?  (Again, Time, National Geographic, etc).
Publication Date:  The magazine will have been published at a specific time.  For example, Wikipedia claims that Time is currently published twice per month on Fridays, so a publication date might be "July 5, 2024".
Issue / Volume: Some magazines might have serialized issue or volume numbers.  I can't think of any off the top of my head, but if such a thing is available, keep track of it.  Again, remember that the goal it to make it easy for others to check your work.
Author:  If you are citing a particular article in a magazine, someone is going to get authorship credit.  This byline is typically right at the start of the article.  Make sure you keep track of that information.
Page(s):  The pages should be numbered.  If you are citing an article, list the page range for the article (if it starts on page 10 and runs to page 15, note something like "pp. 10–15"; if you are only referencing an advertisement on page 31, then "p. 31" might be appropriate).
Other Information:  While this probably won't end up being part of the citation, you should keep track of other information which might help to track down the article.  If you pulled it from some database and have a URL for the information, note that.  Most academic resources have a digital object identifier (DOI) which can be used to track things down.  And so on.

Since the question talks about advertising, I would suggest that the most straightforward approach is to cite each and every issue of the magazine in the bibliography, and give more precise inline references (with page numbers).  Following the general formatting guidelines given by Columbia College (the first result which popped up in my Google bubble when I searched for MLA guidelines regarding citing a magazine), I would expect an inline citation like (Time, 5 July 204, 17), and a bibliography entry (following the unknown author examples for an advertisement) similar to

Advertisements.  Time, 5 July 2024.

Of course, at the end of the day, you do whatever your editor or instructor tells you to do, so the ultimate solution here is to just ask that person how they want you to cite things.

Xander Henderson’s and James K’s answers give excellent general principles.  But since you say you’re being asked to use MLA citation style, then the definitive answer is to go to the MLA style guide itself.
The 1998 edition is online here at the Internet Archive — you may need to sign up for a (free) account to read the whole of it.  Your institution’s library may well have more recent editions available online or in person, but the difference between editions is likely to be negligible.
The MLA also has a website, https://style.mla.org/, presenting a lot of the material from the guide — more accessibly, but less comprehensively and less clearly organised.  Browsing there a little finds a few relevant pages:

How do I cite a periodical over a range of dates?
How do I cite the table of contents of a journal?

Amusingly, these slightly disagree with each other. The former suggests (like James K’s answer) that if you’re discussing the journal as data, then no citation is needed; the latter suggests in a similar situation that you should cite the whole journal issue, and illustrates how.  But this inconsistency itself bears out Xander Henderson’s answer: What really matters is not the precise details of the rules, but the underlying principle, of giving the key information to your readers in a clear and consistent format.

I am glad you answered this question.  I thought about including some of this in my answer, but I was also thinking about a rant about how stupid I find it to put some much emphasis on any particular citation / bibliography style (students often place too much emphasis on the formatting, and not enough on the reasons for citation).  I ultimately decided to cut both from my answer, and appreciate that someone took the time to add in the MLA details.

Does the series have an ISSN, International Standard Serial Number? This is the best identifier for this task.
Probably there is no format for whatever style you use, you have to improvise.

Since there really is no concrete citation, I would pretend it's some sort of product that can be purchased.  In text, I would parenthetically add the publisher and the city of publication.  In the refs cited list, I would include nothing.
If this isn't right, the person in the work chain for the publisher who's in charge of making sure published works adhere to the style sheet (often the copy editor) will likely flag this with an author's query for clarification, and you can start a conversation.  Alternatively, the copy editor might just change it to match the style.
Lastly, don't get hung up on this.  Take you best guess at the right approach.  If it's wrong, somebody will correct you, or it isn't important enough to correct.
